# Why does this try .. catch block not catch the error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

So I'm working on a ban command for my Discord bot, and with Discord role hierarchy and all that, I figured a try ... catch block would do the trick if the pinged user is higher than the bot. Here's my code:

```
try {
    msg.mentions.members.first().ban()
} catch (error) {
    errorOccured = true
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("Error")
    .setDescription(`I do not have permissions to ban <@${msg.mentions.members.first().id}>.`)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setColor('RED')
    return msg.channel.send(embed)
}
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions`

Now, my question is, why does this catch block not catch the error? If I'm just being dumb, please explain why and how I can fix this. Thanks!

Quick edit: I already tried using the `process.on('unhandledRejection' ....`
but for some reason that would also pick up previous errors, and I didn't know how to fix that. If you have a solution for that, even better! :)

Edit 2: Has been fixed by @TinNguyen down in the comments, thanks! ps. @Bergur's solution could probably also have been a solution, but I don't have time to test it out right now.

Comment: Because UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning is not caused by the code in `try`.

Comment: @Teemu well that's just my problem; it is. Nowhere in the rest of my code I use permissions, while the error clearly states that that is the reason it errors.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the library @Teemu but it seems it is caused by the code in the try. If he wants to handle the warning he has to do: `guildMember.ban({ days: 7, reason: 'They deserved it' }) .then(console.log) .catch(console.error);` I might be wrong however.

Comment: Don't know discord, but is the ban method async? Maybe it's just enough to put await in front of msg.mentions,members.first().ban()

Comment: @TinNguyen thank you for the unexpected solution. For whatever reason, a try ... catch block didn't work, while a ```.catch(error => { // code here })``` did work. No clue, why, but it fixed it!

Comment: You have to `await` the promise in order for the catch block to work as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
```

This Warning can be handled with:

```
guildMember.ban({ days: 7, reason: 'They deserved it' })
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error);
```

A general try catch block as shown in the question will not handle that warning.

Comment: The object in the arguments of ```.ban()``` is not needed but optional, and so is the ```.then()```. If you want execute some code when an error occures, make an arrow function in the ```.catch()``` and then put your code in, works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

fetch() returns a Promise, meaning that there are two execution paths, with one delayed. Your general try/catch catches the "main" thread. When the "delayed" Promise execution path returns its result, that try/catch block is far long gone.